# Why I can't open my camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I try to run [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html)  , but it force close happen like this

```
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:294)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:271)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at com.example.Preview.surfaceCreated(Preview.java:37)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1904)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1527)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1263)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-29 10:14:14.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4392):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your device does not have a camera (emulator!) or that you dont have the appropriate permissions defined in your manifest.

```
android.permission.CAMERA
```

Comment: I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> in my menifest already but it still happen the same

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your device, because the tutorial has ask you to add the permission. Edit your AVD and add camera support in hardware

Comment: I try to run it on my device(my phone) but it still show the same force close ,what am I suppose to do?